# Travel to Okinawa from mainland Japan

Tags: air-travel, japan, ferries, tokyo, okinawa

We are visiting Japan in April and I am thinking about a couple of days of sun, bathing and snorkelling in Okinawa. What are the travel options for this? Flying from Tokyo is probably one. Are there over night ferries? How long is the trip and what is the expected cost?

Comment: I don't think there is a ferry from Tokyo but there is a ferry from somewhere in the south, and it's quite a long ride but a friend of mine really likes it and takes it a couple of times each time he's in Japan, which is every year.

Comment: Yes he takes the ferry from Kagoshima City which costs about 15,000 yen. He likes it better than flying even though he's got plenty of money he likes Japanese culture. He also likes the unlimited free green tea on the ferry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A colleague has traveled to Okinawa from the US twice to teach a class. Each time, he flew to  Tokyo (Narita, I believe), and transferred to another flight that stopped in Osaka before heading to Naha.

A list of ferries are listed on this [Japan-Guide](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2355_01.html) website, including ones from Kagoshima or Tokyo. Travel times are over a day.