# Ferry from Motobu, Okinawa to Kagoshima, Kyushu?

Tags: budget, japan, ferries, okinawa, kyushu

I know there is a ferry from [Naha, Okinawa](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Naha) to [Kagoshima, Kyushu](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kagoshima).

I know it takes on the order of a whole day or longer and that its price is approximately equivalent to $150. I am also aware that there might be flights to the main islands of Japan for less.

In my searching I found a mention that the ferry stops at [Motobu in the north of Okinawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motobu,_Okinawa) on the way. Naha is in the south. But I can't seem to find any information on whether it's possible to for a passenger to board the ferry in Motobu and, if so, whether the price might be a little cheaper.

(I am also interested in other ways of getting from Okinawa to the main islands of Japan by sea too but have not come across anything else.)

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/travel-to-okinawa-from-mainland-japan?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A-Line](http://www.aline-ferry.com/index.html) goes from Motobu (本部) to Kagoshima (鹿児島) around twice weekly, but the price difference is marginal:

- [Naha to Kagoshima](http://www.aline-ferry.com/search/searchIndex.php?fromDate=2014%E5%B9%B402%E6%9C%8828%E6%97%A5&startPort=83&endPort=50): ¥15,200 in 2nd class
- [Motobu to Kagoshima](http://www.aline-ferry.com/search/searchIndex.php?fromDate=2014%E5%B9%B402%E6%9C%8828%E6%97%A5&startPort=84&endPort=50): ¥14,300 in 2nd class

And by remarkable coincidence, the [prices on competitor Marix](http://www.marix-line.co.jp/cgi-bin/07carriage-info/file/passenger_charge.pdf?nocache) are *precisely* the same.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble reading the sites even with the hostel owner here. It looks like a ferry goes from Motobu every second day, alternating between either the two companies or between two boats owned by the same company?

Comment: That's about ten dollars AUD cheaper, the price of a night's accommodation or two cheap meals. But more importantly it gives me a reason to hitchhike to the north of the island knowing that I won't have to come back to Naha again just to move on.

Comment: The popup schedule on the marixline site uses a colour code with yellow for "Queen Coral Plus" and orange for "Coral Queen 8". We are not sure who owns which ferry and whether the schedule includes their competitor's info.

Comment: Both Queens are Marix's own ferries: http://www.marixline.com/page0111.html and http://www.marixline.com/page0112.html .  A-Line's are Naminoue http://www.aline-ferry.com/kagoshima/ship_naminoue.html and Akebono http://www.aline-ferry.com/kagoshima/ship_akebono.html .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I can only provide the [site that lists the Ferries](http://www.kotsu-okinawa.org/en/index_ferry.html) running to/from various locations in Okinawa.  It lists 2 lines that make a stop at Motobu, [Marix line](http://www.marixline.com/) and [A Line](http://www.aline-ferry.com/) both of which provide daily service from Motobu.  Both sites are in Japanese and I currently have problem with online translation.

Comment: Yes I couldn't make sense of those two sites either and my hostel host wasn't around today. I almost included the links in my question ...

Comment: My current understanding is that the two ferry lines take turns on alternate days for their departures with most other things such as times and prices being the same.