# Can I stop at Amami on the ferry between Okinawa and Kagoshima without having to pay more?

Tags: japan, ferries, islands, okinawa

I'm currently on the main island of Okinawa Japan. I intend to take the ferry to Kagoshima, Kyushu when I'm ready to leave but ...

I know both ferry companies that operate the route make a stop at another Okinawan island about half way to Kyushu called [Amami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amami_Islands).

But I don't know if I have to buy two separate tickets if I want to spend some time there.

Or is there any kind of special ticket that allows something like a hop-on hop-off service for this route?

[According to Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Amami_Islands#By_ferry) the ferry prices are:

- Kagoshima (11 hours) ¥8,800
- Naha (13 hours) ¥9,300

That comes to ¥18,100 which seems quite a bit more than [the direct fare from Naha to Kagoshima](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/24574/140): ¥15,200 - **Is there a way to make it cheaper?**

(I'll be going the cheapest way possible, which I assume is 2nd class, and actually from Motobu rather than Naha.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't prove a negative, but as far as I can tell by looking at the sites of A-Line and Marix, the answer is **no**, they don't offer any sort of hop-on-hop-off ticket, nor do you get any "stopovers" if you buy a longer ticket.

There's a third option from Amami to Kagoshima, the once-weekly [Tokara Ferry](http://www.tokara.jp/access/index.html) via the tiny and obscure [Tokara Islands](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokara_Islands) (long on my personal to-do list), but this costs even more at ¥11,620 one-way.

Comment: Yes I saw the Tokara option and it caught my attention too. But with my funds dwindling the higher cost was disappointing. But is this the price for one-way from which place? Okinawa or Kagoshima?

Comment: Naze (Amami Oshima) to Kagoshima via Tokara.  Again, stops cost money, but not much: eg. Naze-Kuchinoshima-Kagoshima is 6410+6010=Y12420, or 800 yen extra.